# How to design a stable table?

Tags: statics, weight

Imagine a round table, standing on one central leg. The central leg has a base for balance. That base is what I am referring to.

What physics do I need to understand to design a stable table?

For instance, I want to be able to figure out how large and heavy the base should be to keep the table from toppling for a given tabletop, and how to allow for a heavy weight to be placed on one edge of the table.

Comment: The center of gravity has to be above the area (or base) of support, so if you draw a plumb line trough the total center of gravity of your table and the test mass together, it needs to be inside the area which is created by the contact points of the table with the ground. If you specify the density of the materials most 3d CAD tools will calculate the center of gravity for you, I believe.

Comment: Hi @LearnIT. I've edited your question a bit to focus on the general ideas in physics that are relevant instead of the details of how to solve your particular problem. If you're not happy with the changes, you can [roll back to an earlier version](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/191224/edit).

Comment: You need to define what constraints you want to place on the design.  For example, a round tabletop with no leg and no base would be extremely stable.  Or, if your base is larger than your tabletop, that will be extremely stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the net moment (or [torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque)) about a point on the rim of the base. Find the equilibrium state where the moment due to the weight of the object at the edge of the table balances that of the weight of the table itself, as you adjust the weight of the object. Anything greater than the weight you get for the object after calculation will topple the table. Adjust your base accordingly.